# Is there a way to see my messages sent by other clients in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, xmpp, google-hangouts, facebook-chat

When I have multiple Facebook Chat or Google Hangouts official clients connected to the same account, all messages that I type in one client appear on the other.

But if one of this clients is Pidgin, pidgin won't display the messages typed in other clients connected to the same account. Is there any way to enable this behavior? If not is it technically possible to implement this on an XMPP client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant XMPP extension is [XEP-0280: Message Carbons](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html):

> In order to keep all IM clients for a user engaged in a conversation, outbound messages are carbon-copied to all interested resources.

It needs to be enabled by your XMPP server *and* supported by your XMPP client.

I don’t use Pidgin, but according to their [list of supported XEPs](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/SupportedXEPs), XEP-0280 is *not* supported.

There is a ticket about implementing it: [Support for XEP-0280: Message Carbons](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/15508). Several people report that the patch works for them, but it doesn’t seem to be implemented yet.

Comment: FWIW, a few days ago a [bounty was offered](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1410118-support-for-xep-0280-message-carbons) for implementing this feature.